# How to write a simple macro in MIT Scheme?

Tags: common-lisp, mit-scheme

I am trying to translate this simple Common Lisp macro code to MIT Scheme code:

```
(defmacro calc (a op b)
  (list op a b))

(calc 2 + 3)
```

The above code prints `5` as expected.

How do I do the same thing in MIT scheme? Here is my attempt:

```
(defmacro (calc a op b)
  (list op a b))

(calc 2 + 3)
```

The above code fails with this error:

```
Unbound variable: b
```

What is the right way to write this code in MIT Scheme?

Comment: use DEFINE-SYNTAX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While many Scheme implementations has `defmacro` it differs if it has arguments like in Common Lisp, Scheme or if the expression is also a special form. It is not portable. From R5RS you can use `syntax-rules:

```
(define-syntax calc
  (syntax-rules () 
   ((_ a op b)   ; pattern  
    (op a b))))  ; expansion

(calc 4 + 3) ; ==> 7
```

Comment: What does `_` in the beginning of `(_ a op b)` mean?

Comment: @LoneLearner `_` is a symbol like any other. It will match `calc` in the pattern. Some like to use the name eg. `(calc a op b)` but you never actually use the first symbol so `_` is often used.